# XML: child and parent with the same name

Tags: xml

In valid XML, is it possible to have children with the same name as their parent? For example:

```
<parent>
    <child>
    </child>
    <parent>
    </parent>
</parent>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have included XML code in my post, but it is not visible. How can I make it visible?

Comment: I edited the post for you. In the future: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: How about a (first level) child element with the same name as the root node?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing aside from a specific [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) or [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) that would prevent this.

Comment: Does the same apply when a top level element has the same name as the rood node?

Comment: The root node has a special meaning in a well-formed XML document, it can only occur once and there can't be 2 of them. It's also appended to the namespace after a `#` to create a unique identification. That's why I thought that there may have been a difference, but all the same I wasn't really expecting it.

Comment: That there can only be one root node has to do with XML structure; it says nothing about tag names.

Comment: Your're right, but like I said I was only making sure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is even valid (sometimes) in XHTML. for example the following is valid XHTML (within a page body):

```
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but `<p><p></p></p>` is not valid XHTML (or HTML) for semantic reasons, so XHTML is not necessarily a good example.